# How to catagorize timestamp based on hours in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to categorize the timestamp by the HOUR using the arrival column  categories like ['00.00 - 06.00', '06.00 - 10.00', '10.00 - 14.00', '14.00 - 18.00', '18.00 - 00.00']). I am very new to this kindly help.

[image: THe table looks like]

the table has all the time durations from 00.00 to 23.00 just the sample is shown here.

Kindly help me to do the categories and add them.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! There are **huge** indiscrepencies in your data - there are no trips that either start between 00:00 - 06:00! Please construct a fiddle at dbfiddle.uk with data that makes sense and give us your desired result from that **consistent** data!

Comment: Plus, it makes no sense to add occupancies over different trips - you could get results way in excess of 100 - what would make more sense is to have a capacity per trip and then either a number or percentage of occupants - then you take the average of all capacities over your time period and divide that by the total number of passengers over all trips for that period to get a **realistic** occupancy per period!

Comment: Create timeranges table with needed ranges (start-finish) and join it to your query datasource as a base.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (so that we can Copy & Paste it). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sure I will follow that here after. Thank you

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question, showing all the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a list of start/end times and do a left join against that together with a group by:

Something along the lines:

```
with times (begin_time, end_time) as (
  values 
     (time '00:00', time '06:00'),
     (time '06:00', time '10:00'),
     (time '10:00', time '14:00'),
     (time '14:00', time '18:00'),
     (time '18:00', time '24:00')
)
select tm.begin_time, tm.end_time, count(*)
from times tm
  left join the_table t 
         on t.arrival::time >= tm.begin_time
        and t.arrival::time < tm.end_time
group by tm.begin_time, tm.end_time
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: Would something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fde493c320a71b50393e47f53741ac62) be better? I also think that including a date component would be an idea - it's unlikely that one would want to do this for only one day? And does a `TIME` of 24:00 actually exist?